# How do you build a class around JSON from an API?

Tags: python, oop, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to OOP and I'm trying to model a Facebook event. I've defined a class but my init method is throwing a `NameError`.

```
class Event:
    'A Facebook event object'

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.eid = item['eid'] 
        self.name = item['name'][:255]
        self.start_time = item['start_time']
        self.end_time = item['end_time']
```

> ```
>  File "file.py", line 12, in Event  
>     self.name = item['name'][:255]  
> NameError: name 'item' is not defined
> ```

The item I want to pass into the init is an element of the JSON output of Facebook's API. e.g.

```
    {
      "eid": "534198190011161", 
      "name": "Name of event", 
      "start_time": "2015-04-13T22:30:00+0100", 
      "end_time": "2015-07-31T03:00:00+0100"
    }
```

I'm really struggling with OPP and APIs in general, can anyone help me?

Comment: From the error message it looks like you may have an indentation error.  Check your indentation.

Comment: How are you creating a new instance of `Event` and passing in the JSON right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need Python JSON parsing.

```
import json

json_data = """{
  "eid": "534198190011161", 
  "name": "Name of event", 
  "start_time": "2015-04-13T22:30:00+0100", 
  "end_time": "2015-07-31T03:00:00+0100"
}"""

class Event:
    """A Facebook event object"""
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.eid = item['eid']
        self.name = item['name'][:255]
        self.start_time = item['start_time']
        self.end_time = item['end_time']

item = Event(json.loads(data))

print(item.name)
```

> u'Name of event'

Note that you should NOT use single or double quotes to describe a method. Use the triple quote aka the docstring. You could also use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) for your event, which I leave to your discretion ;-) .

Comment: I pasted your class over mine... it's identical, yet yours works and mine doesn't. Very confused, and grateful for your help.